# Find server address on ubuntu

Tags: dns

How do I find the dns server of my router 192.168.1.1 in a file?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

/etc/resolv.conf

Name server is 127.0.0.1

Comment: So you are looking for a file that has the name of your serve? You can just go to `localhost` can't you? The DNS server will not be part of your computer...

Comment: ya i know dns will not part of a computer but there should a file to denote my router or modem . (192.168.1.1)

Comment: Okay, I don't think that exists... Why do you need to have a file with it in?

Comment: My boss is asking how 127.0.0.1 find an remote address :(

Comment: the command `ifconfig` will give you the ip address.

Comment: @Tim you probably misunderstood - he is not asking for the hosts's own IP-address.

Answer (score 1):

On current desktop versions of Ubuntu (using `NetworkManager`), DNS resolution is provided via a local process called `dnsmasq` that listens on port 53 of `localhost` - that's why your DNS server appears to be `127.0.0.1` in this instance.

In turn, `dnsmasq` gets its information from the upstream server specified as part of the interface definition, either manually or as part of its DHCP provision. If you are using a DHCP-supplied upstream DNS then that will be visible as part of the DNS lease, so it should be visible in your DHCP client's lease file, for example `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` - although it would be more usual to access that information programatically either using `nm-tool` or `nmcli` e.g.

```
$ nmcli -f IP4 dev list
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.1.16/24, gw = 192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
```

If you have specified an upstream DNS server manually (i.e. are using DHCP only for addressing information), then you would need to look in the connection definition file - for example in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<CON_NAME>`

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which DNS servers your machine uses by running

```
nm-tool
```

Comment: ya Kat i can use the nm-tool to saw my dns server but i want to locate in a file in /etc or any other location ..